# Android layout issue - item is hidden when other view is too long

Tags: android, layout

Hello for I am creating layout for list of users where is name and sometimes notification icon. The problem is that the name (green rectangle) can have any width and when the name is too long the notification icon (red rectangle) get hidden by its container (black rectangle) bounds.

http://postimg.org/image/6o7np9lx3/

What it should do is that, when the notification icon is gone the name can take any width its container allow. But when the notification icon appears it never should hide it on the right side of container, but only move it to the right side. And also the notification icon should be on the right side of the name. 
Last thing the width of container depends on screen width.

So basically this:

http://postimg.org/image/94a0rxy1d/

1. notification and short text
2. notification and long text
3. No notification and long text

Hope I was clear:-)
And I would upload image here directly, but I don't have enough reputation...

Edit: Adding layout i created:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/CMCname"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ff181818" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/CMCname"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/CMCMessageCounterBG" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/CMCmessageCounter"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post the layout you have created.

Answer (score 0):

If your icon is static then you can directly put it as drawable right to textview and it will work fine.

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/text"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:gravity="left|center"
android:padding="10dp"
android:text="Your text goes here" />
```

Hope it works. :)

Comment: But in this layout the notification icon will always be on the right side of the container even when the name is short - See the second image first row layout.

Comment: Is your notification icon static?? means you are fetching it from server or directly from drawable folder.

Comment: Yes it is static image from resources.